# Can't figure out how to get results of an AppleScript to print to a text file

Tags: applescript

The code below works. It returns the list variable in the results tab of the script editor. I want to write that to a text file.

```
set A to text
set B to text
set C to text
set D to text
set E to text
set F to text
set G to text
set H to text
set I to text
set J to text
set K to text
set L to text
set M to text
set N to text
set O to text
set P to text
set Q to text
set R to text
set S to text
set T to text
set U to text
set V to text
set W to text
set X to text
set Y to text
set Z to text
set Alphabet1 to {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"}
set Alphabet2 to {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"}
set Alphabet3 to {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"}

set IdleLoop2 to "set value of cell (µ∑†∏µ & LastRowCrypto + 1) to current¥Price"

set findText3 to "∑"
set findText4 to "†"
set findText5 to "∏"
set findText6 to "¥"
set ListOfExcel to {}
repeat with A from 1 to length of Alphabet1
    set replaceText4 to item A of Alphabet1
    set newText4 to do shell script "sed 's|" & quoted form of findText3 & ¬
        "|" & quoted form of replaceText4 & "|g' <<< " & quoted form of IdleLoop2
    copy newText4 to the end of ListOfExcel
end repeat

repeat with B from 1 to length of Alphabet2
    repeat with D from 1 to 26
        set IdleLoop3 to item D of ListOfExcel
        set replaceText5 to item B of Alphabet2
        set newText5 to do shell script "sed 's|" & quoted form of findText4 & ¬
            "|" & quoted form of replaceText5 & "|g' <<< " & quoted form of IdleLoop3
        copy newText5 to the end of ListOfExcel
    end repeat
end repeat
repeat with C from 1 to length of Alphabet3
    repeat with E from 27 to 53
        set IdleLoop4 to item E of ListOfExcel
        set replaceText6 to item B of Alphabet3
        set newText6 to do shell script "sed 's|" & quoted form of findText5 & ¬
            "|" & quoted form of replaceText6 & "|g' <<< " & quoted form of IdleLoop4
        copy newText6 to the end of ListOfExcel
    end repeat
end repeat

return ListOfExcel
```

I've tried this:

```
set the logFile to ((path to desktop) as text) & "DOG.txt"
set the logText to ListOfExcel
try
    open for access file the logFile with write permission
    write (logText & return) to file the logFile starting at eof
    close access file the logFile
on error
    try
        close access file the logFile
    end try
end try
```

And tried this:

```
do shell script "echo " (I forgot the rest)
```

And tried this:

```
write ListOfExcel to textFile
```

But those ideas don’t seem to work.

I just don't understand the things necessary to change the format of the list variable, how to call the text file into existence with permissions and have AppleScript write to that file.

Comment: With a script like this you need to reduce it to a minimum form necessary to reproduce the issue. As it stands there are too many potential fail points for anyone to quickly work through where is went wrong. Reducing it in this way will also help you to see where the issue may lie.

Comment: RE: "I want to write that to a text file." --   Just to be clear `ListOfExcel` is a _list_, do you want to write it to a _file_ as a _list_ or _text_?

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing what the working *script* in your OP and its *contents* for the `ListOfExcel` *list*, I'm not sure why you would want to write that to a *file*, however, assuming you want to write the *contents* of the `ListOfExcel` *list* to a *file* as *text*, then replace `return ListOfExcel` in the working *code* shown in your OP with the following *example* **AppleScript** *code*, which is using the *variables* shown in your OP:

```applescript
set the logFile to ((path to desktop) as text) & "DOG.txt"

set {TID, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to ¬
    {AppleScript's text item delimiters, linefeed}
set logText to ListOfExcel as text
set text item delimiters to TID

writeToFile(logText, logFile, true)

on writeToFile(theData, theFile, overwriteExistingContent)
    try
        set theFile to theFile as string
        if theFile contains "/" then
            set theOpenedFile to open for access theFile with write permission
        else
            set theOpenedFile to open for access file theFile with write permission
        end if
        if overwriteExistingContent is true then set eof of theOpenedFile to 0
        write theData to theOpenedFile starting at eof
        close access theOpenedFile
        return true
    on error
        try
            close access file theFile
        end try
        return false
    end try
end writeToFile
```

---

**Notes**:

The `writeToFile(theText, theFile, overwriteExistingContent)` *handler* is a slightly modified *handler* from: [Reading and Writing Files](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/ReadandWriteFiles.html)

The *handler* from the linked **Apple** support document was modified to handle both **POSIX** and **HFS+** *file paths*, and its *name* was changed too.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>